# Get annotation pin tap event MapKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mkmapview, mkannotation

i have an array of a class. and in a mkmapview i append some annotation pins.

```
var events = [Events]()

   for event in events {
        let eventpins = MKPointAnnotation()
        eventpins.title = event.eventName
        eventpins.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLat, longitude: event.eventLon)
        mapView.addAnnotation(eventpins)
    }
```

With the delegate of map i've implemented a function

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print(view.annotation?.title! ?? "")
}
```

How can I get which row of the array `events` is being tapped?
Because i want to segue in another ViewController and i would like to send this Class Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a custom annotation class, like:

```
class EventAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
    var myEvent:Event?
}
```

Then, when you add your annotations, you'll link the `Event` with the custom annotation:

```
for event in events {
    let eventpins = EventAnnotation()
    eventpins.myEvent = event // Here we link the event with the annotation
    eventpins.title = event.eventName
    eventpins.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: event.eventLat, longitude: event.eventLon)
    mapView.addAnnotation(eventpins)
}
```

Now, you can access the event in the delegate function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    // first ensure that it really is an EventAnnotation:
    if let eventAnnotation = view.annotation as? EventAnnotation {
        let theEvent = eventAnnotation.myEvent
        // now do somthing with your event
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!